# Audio Streaming over TCP from Android to PC

Tags: android, tcp, audio-streaming, voice-recognition

Recently I was digging all around but was unable to get some decent solution. My problem is I want to send audio recorded from Android Device to Server running at PC which will receive this audio and will use windows speech recognition and will try to convert it into text. I have searched a lot. But couldn't find any solution. I have tried:

[Android-Audio Streaming From Pc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4992771/android-audio-streaming-from-pc)

[Android: Streaming audio over TCP Sockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2749236/android-streaming-audio-over-tcp-sockets)

[Java - Broadcast voice over Java sockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7728850/java-broadcast-voice-over-java-sockets)

http://eurodev.blogspot.com/2009/09/raw-audio-manipulation-in-android.html

Can you help me??

Comment: This is actually how the normal voice recognition works.  Why not just use the built-in voice recognition and send text where you need to?

Comment: I need it to work on Intranet not internet... It doesn't work if you don't have internet connection... :|
What I need is to send voice recorded from android device to PC where it will be sent to Windows Speech Recognition Api for conversion to text. And then this converted text will be sent back to android device...

Comment: Hey @Awais, did you figured out how to send voice over tcp to system.speech? if so can you share some insights?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

since I'm new and cannot comment on your question or ask for clarifications, but just answer it, I'll do my best here.

This is how I would try to solve the problem if it was mine:

- record the audio on the android device
- send it to the laptop via email/ftp/whatever transport is easier for me
- open it in the laptop and send it to the Windows Speech Recognition Api for conversion to text
- send it back via email/ftp/whatever transport is easier for me

hope it helps.

Gustavo.